# C++ Valgrind error Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c++, valgrind, memcheck

I have a problem with my C++ code as valgrind is giving me the error (Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)) at lines highlighted below. I tried initializing "**type**" with an empty string, but doesn't seems to be working.
Any help here much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

nandanator

```
int AB_CD::checkType(string & str)
{
    int tmp = 0;

    string type;


    while (getNextSubstring(str, type))
    {
        if (type == "AAA")     <<<<< ----- Valgrind error pointing here 
        {
            tmp |= static_cast<int>(TYPE_AAA);
        }
        else if (type == "BBB") <<<<< ----- Valgrind error pointing here 
        {
            tmp |= static_cast<int>(TYPE_BBB);
        }
        else if (type == "CCC") <<<<< ----- Valgrind error pointing here 
        {
            tmp |= static_cast<int>(TYPE_CCC);
        }
        else
    {
        //Print a warning
    }

    }

    return tmp;

}



bool AB_CD::getNextSubstring(string & input, string & substring)
{
    bool found_substring = false;

    string::size_type start = input.find_first_not_of(" ,");
    string::size_type end = input.find_first_of(" ,", start);

    if (start != string::npos)
    {
        substring = input.substr(start, end-start);
        input.erase(start, end-start);
        found_substring = true;
    }
    return found_substring;
}
```

Comment: AB_CD::getNextSubstring() must return true or the while() loop would not be entered. That means `substring = input.substr(start, end-start);` hapens and must be setting your type string to something that is uninitialized. Note: I recommend changing your API for getNextSubstring(). Maybe make it `string getNextSubstring(const string & input);` and throw an exception when nothing is found.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Thank you. :). I shall try this out and get back.

Comment: New snippet looks like below.
`string AB_CD::getNextSubstring1(string & input)
{
 
    string substring = "" ;
    substring.empty();

    string::size_type start = input.find_first_not_of(" ,");
    string::size_type end = input.find_first_of(" ,", start);

    if (start != string::npos)
    {
        substring = input.substr(start, end-start);
        input.erase(start, end-start);
    }
    return substring;
    }`
..
    `type = getNextSubstring1(str);`
...
Still I am getting the error.
`if (type == "AAA")      << Here
        {
            tmp |= static_cast<int>(TYPE_AAA);
        }`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Could you please comment?

Comment: You didn't check or fix the 'input.substr(start, end-start)' that is probably corrupting your string